# Linux HTTP server Network Settings

Tags: linux, networking, dhcp

I'm having a hard time to find a network configuration for a system that I'm developing. I start by stating that I'm not a network expert, so i'm sorry for something that is not so well explained.

I'm developing a system that is composed by 3 linux devices. One of them is an HTTP Server. Until now all 3 linux devices were configured to have Fixed IPs (192.168.1.20/24 - 192.168.1.21/24 - 192.168.1.22/24). This way any computer (User) in the network could access the HTTP server.

Now I'm trying to integrate my system into a third party device. And here comes the problem.

- This device needs access to the HTTP Server.
- This device has a fixed IP 235.* .* .* .
- This device has a DHCP Server
- This device is optional. Sometimes is present in the network, sometimes is not.
- My HTTP server needs to obtain an IPv4 address via DHCP (from this third party device)
- The HTTP server needs to advertise the HTTP service to the third party device via multicast DNS.

I can make this system work by configuring the HTTP server to get a dynamic IP from the DHCP server (235.* .* .*).But this way:

- the users on the network lose access to the HTTP Server.
- when I connect my system to a router and to the third party device it's problematic (because now my system is connected to 2 DHCP servers - router and third party device).
- when neither the router nor the third party device is connected there is no DHCP server in the network, and I lose access to the HTTP Server.

Possible solutions that I tried but was not able to make it work:

- Multiple IPs in the HTTP server (one Fixed and one dynamic). Problem when there are 2 DHCP servers.
- Access via host name (users do not have to know the system IP to access to it) -> this way I can have just the dynamic IP. I think this solution might bring problem in other networks.

Does someone has any ideia what could be the network settings for the HTTP server and the other 2 linux devices?

I will leave here also a diagram of the network (I dont know if it is well done or not but it might help):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eit8j.png

Things in grey are not always present in the network.

If something is not well explained please just ask. I'm new here :)

Answer (score 0):

HTTP server could has two static IPs: from 192.168.1.0/24 network and 235.*.*.* to server "third party device"'s requests.
I don't know which kind of linux is on it, but for test you can add interface to same network device:

```
$ sudo ip addr add 235.0.0.2/24 dev eth0
```

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that the IP for the network 235... cannot be fixed. It must aquire a dynamic ip from the third party device.

Comment: And if I set it up to have a static IP from 192.168.1.0/24... and a dynamic IP from the other network. What happens when my system is connected at the same time to my router and to the third party device? There are now 2 dhcp servers in the network. And I want my system to get a IP from the third party device dhcp server, and not from my router dhcp server.

Comment: 2 dhcps can't live in one subnet